# Why doesn't gluUnProject() seem to behave?

Tags: java, opengl

I am trying to find the coordinates of my mouse on a flat 3D surface. After googling a bit on that, I found out that you use gluUnProject for doing so. So, I implemented that. Here is my code (when taking away the parts that are not interesting):

```
public class Input {
private FloatBuffer modelView = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
private FloatBuffer projection = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
private IntBuffer viewport = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(16);
private FloatBuffer location = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(3);
private FloatBuffer winZ = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(1);

public float[] getMapCoords(int x, int y)
{
    modelView.clear().rewind();
    projection.clear().rewind();
    viewport.clear().rewind();
    location.clear().rewind();
    winZ.clear().rewind();

    glGetFloat(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelView);
    glGetFloat(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
    glGetInteger(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

    float winX = (float)x;
    float winY = (float)viewport.get(3) - (float)y;

    glReadPixels(x, (int)winY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, winZ);
    gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ.get(0), modelView, projection, viewport, location);
    return new float[] {location.get(0), location.get(1), location.get(2)};
}
}
```

When I call this function, passing in the X and Y coordinates of the mouse, I get some numbers that increase by 100 for every pixel I move with my mouse (it should be around 1). After doing some prints from various variables, I found out that the winZ buffer contains the value 1.0. My gluPerspective is set up in such a way that its near clipping point it at 0.1 and its far point at 10000, which would explain why the number is increasing that rapidly. Yet I don't know how to force openGl to use my flat plane instead for finding this distance.

So now I am wondering; if this is the correct/best/easiest method for finding the mouse coordinates on a surface in the 3D world, what could I be doing wrong? If it is not, what is a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct method to use. You are probably just calling it at the point where the matrices do not contain "good values" (might be caused by glPush/PopMatrix() functions in your code).

To confirm you are getting good coordinates, draw a single GL_POINT at the coordinates you get, after you get them (disable depth test and increase point size to, say, 10 pixels). If the point is moving under your mouse, then the calculated coords are correct but the matrices are not.

Comment: I actually solved it myself quite a while ago. I can't actually remember how though, but have some reputation anyway :)

Comment: thanks :) next time, try to post the solution for the others. also, it would mark your question as "answered" and remove it from the list of unanswered questions, which is a good thing.